# Excel 2016 alphabethical sort doesn't seem to work correctly

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, language, sorting

I use an English installation of Windows, but an Swedish installation of Office 2016. When I sorted a couple of rows alphabethically today, the result was very strange. Apparently, Excel 2016 doesn't differentiate between `v` and `w`. I don't know if that's expected behaviour in English (I'm not a native English speaker), but in Swedish `v` definitely comes before `w` in dictionaries.

A part of the troubling list of rows:

```
StoraEnso A
Swedbank A
Svenska Cellulosa SCA B
THQ Nordic B
```

If `v` and `w` are lexicographically equal, the sorting is performed correctly. However, since I'm using a Swedish installation of Excel, I expected that `Swedbank A` and `Svenska Cellulosa SCA B` would be in opposite places, like this:

```
StoraEnso A
Svenska Cellulosa SCA B
Swedbank A
THQ Nordic B
```

Before asking this question here, I've only found this question that is somewhat similar, but not quite (at least not the answer), since Å, Ä and Ö seem to be sorted correctly in the same list: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/offce-2016-excel-sorting-doesnt-understand/44d35d64-c23e-48a3-9523-bb09e6cc1964

My input language is set to Swedish (default). Is there a way I can check to see which language my worksheet uses?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work.. but it may worth a try.. || try to open it in in Office356 (online) or google docs, and test the sorting (to verify the language).

Comment: @p._phidot_ Thanks for the suggestion. I converted it to Google Spreadsheet and sorted it and there the sorting is correct. The question now is how I force Excel to use Swedish...

Comment: Glad the trial worth the check. || [ Seriously, I'm not sure how to check the language setting too ] || But very curious on going through my next list of checks : How does the file behave when it was opened in other people PC (with English excel + input settings). || IMHO, If it behaves the same then the file language is host (PC) language independent, if it behaves differently (than the Swedish Excel), the setting is host dependent.